# XeTeX fonts in figures and captions

Tags: xetex

I want to use XeTeX for English-only documents but I found a problem. When I use a non-default font (times or palatino), text in the figures and their captions remain in the default font. MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}  
\setmainlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Palatino Linotype}

\begin{document}
\noindent{}The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
\begin{figure}[h]
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
\caption{Caption of the fox}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need polyglossia for an English document but anyay you want to specify the main document font, here I just use the fontspec declaration

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}  
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}

\begin{document}
\showthe\font
\noindent{}The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
\begin{figure}[h]\showthe\font
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
\caption{Caption of the fox}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, David. One caveat for others who might read this: when I changed polyglossia to fontspec I got an error and it took me a while to figure that this came from the aux file. Erasing and regenerating the file solved the problem.